# Chart control for WinRT

Tags: windows-phone-7, charts, telerik, controls, windows-runtime

On Telerik blog I found article about create chart controls from WP7 Telerik controls.

http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/11-10-07/radchart-for-windows-8-winrt-the-compilation.aspx

I am trying to re-create scenario but I still something is wrong. I am not sure if I do it in right project (WP7).

Is someone did it and could explain step by step how to recompile this libs?

Many thanks

Comment: That article is not about developing for Windows Phone - they do have a [chart for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#chart), but that article is not about it

Answer (score 1):

Thats not for Windows Phone . It explains about Windows 8....

You can try the Charts for WP7 using RadControls for Windows Phone .

Below are few links to get you started

[Chart Controls for WP7 - Telerik RadControls](http://cdn.static.viddler.com/flash/as3/full-publisher.swf?ref=www.telerik.com&key=ae0adc74&iframe=true&width=800&height=520)

[RadControl for WP7 - Documentation - Charts](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radchart-overview.html)

Comment: You can also view the video library on Windows Phone for more chart help. http://tv.telerik.com/products/windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not apply to Windows Phone; you need Visual Studio 2011 and Windows 8 Consumer Preview in order to use those controls!

There is RadChart for Windows Phone, but that article is for Metro apps in Windows 8!

Comment: Ok,
So I created a new metro app project in VS 2011. I added Windows Phone Controls references

I add on page:

   `xmlns:telerik ="using=Telerik.Windows.Controls">` to namspaces and

<telerik:RadCartesianChart></telerik:RadCartesianChart>  

But control is still unknown.

Comment: I must be missing something here...you created "a new metro app project in VS 2011" and added the Windows Phone Controls referencs?? What are you expecting to achieve here? Those controls are for Windows 8, not for Windows Phone 7! Metro app project is for Windows 8, not for Windows Phone 7!